# Pointwise standard errors for a logistic regression fit with statsmodels

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, python, standard-error

**Source**

*An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R*, found here: https://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf

**Task**

I'm trying to replicate the example of a polynomial logistic regression on the "Wage" dataset on page 267/8.

**Theory outline**

According to the book, once predictions have been made, confidence intervals can be calculated like so. For a model of the form $$\hat{f}(x_0)=\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x_0+\hat{\beta_2}x_0^2+\hat{\beta_3}x_0^3+\hat{\beta_4}x_0^4,$$  with a $5\times 5$ covariance matrix $C$ and vector $l_0^T=(1, x_0, x_0^2, x_0^3, x_0^4)$, the pointwise standard error is the square root of $\text{Var}[\hat{f}(x_0)]=l_0^TCl_0$. So for every $x_0$ in our dataset we have a plot of predictions $\hat{f}(x_0)$ and a plot of upper and lower confidence intervals $\hat{f}(x_0)\pm(2\times \text{Var}[\hat{f}(x_0)])$.

For a logistic regression, the same principal can be applied, but the confidence is around the conditional probability logit function, as opposed to the predictions that come straight from the formula above.

**Data and approach / reusable code**

First of all, this is the code for generating the logistic regression model and plotting the results. This bit is fine and I've successfully reproduced what is in the book:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from statsmodels.datasets import get_rdataset
from statsmodels.discrete import discrete_model

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
polynomial_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)

# Get dataset from the R package
data = get_rdataset("Wage", package="ISLR") 
df = data.data.reset_index() 

# Split data into wage (response, y) and age (predictor, X_orig)
y = df.wage
X_orig = df.filter(['age'], axis=1)
# Get the polynomial features from the predictor variable
X = polynomial_feat.fit_transform(X_orig) 

# Set up the test ages for a smooth results plot
X_test = np.linspace(18, 80, 1000)
X_test = X_test[:,np.newaxis] 
X_test_poly = polynomial_feat.fit_transform(X_test) 

# Create a dummy response variable, 1 if wage > 250k and 0 otherwise
y_dummy = pd.DataFrame({'wage': y[:]}) 
y_dummy['wage_split'] = np.where(y_dummy['wage'] > 250, 1, 0) 
y_dummy = y_dummy.drop(['wage'], axis=1)

# Fit a logistic regression model with statsmodels
logit_model = discrete_model.Logit(y_dummy, X).fit() 
# Get predictions, i.e. Pr(Wage > 250 | Age)
y_preds = logit_model.predict(X_test_poly)

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8)) 
plt.plot(X_test, y_preds, 'b-') 
plt.ylim(top=0.2) 
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("P(Wage > 250 | Age)")
plt.title("Probability of Earning > 250k with Logistic Regression")
```

[image: Plot of logistic regression probabilities]

So now I attempt to plot the confidence intervals. I don't *think* there is a method to do this directly in statsmodels (please correct me if I'm wrong).

**My issue**

My issue here is in the calculation of the pointwise standard errors and the confidence intervals. We know that the response values for the logistic regression model must be $y\in [0, 1]$, since it is a conditional probability.

The problem is that for every $x_0$, the value of $$\sqrt{l_0^TCl_0}$$ is going to be relatively large. I can demonstrate this by using the first age value, $x_0=18$:

```
# Get the covariance matrix from the model class
C = logit_model.normalized_cov_params
x = 18.
L_T = np.array([1, x, x**2, x**3, x**4])

# Compute the pointwise standard error, as outlined above
L_T = np.matrix(L_T)
L = np.transpose(L_T)
C = np.matrix(C)

var_f = np.matmul(np.matmul(L_T, C), L)
var_f = np.asarray(var_f)[0][0]
pointwise_se = np.sqrt(var_f) 
print(pointwise_se)
```

The output of this is `pointwise_se = 6.14`.

From the plot above, I can see that the prediction of $\text{Pr}(\text{Wage} > 250 | x=18)$ is close to zero, and from the example provided in the book I can see that the confidence interval around this value is not wide, and definitely doesn't go negative or greater than 1.

If I was to get a confidence interval from a pointwise standard error of $6.14$, the plot would be silly, and not a replication of that in the book.

**My question**

What am I doing wrong in my calculation of the pointwise standard error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are doing logistic regression and not simple linear regression, the equation $\hat f(x_0)=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_0+\hat\beta_2x_0^2+\hat\beta_3x_0^3+\hat\beta_4x_0^4$ does not refer to the probability of earning >250K, but to the *logit* of that probability. This is the same as saying that logistic regression is a linear model that uses logit as a link function.

So, you have to define functions to convert between probabilities and logits (maybe they are already implemented in Numpy or something, but they are simple enough to type):

```
def logit(p):
    return np.log(p/(1-p))

def invlogit(x):
    # inverse function of logit
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

Now, we have to apply the pointwise SE you calculated to the logit of the point estimates, and then convert back to probabilities:

```
upper_limit = invlogit(logit(y_pred)+1.96*std_err)
lower_limit = invlogit(logit(y_pred)-1.96*std_err)
```

Where `std_err` is an array with the standard errors of $\hat f(x)$ that you correctly calculated. Then, `upper_limit` and `lower_limit` will give an interval around the estimated probability.

Comment: computational aside: In statsmodels, this is implemented for GLM in `get_prediction`, and can be used for a Logit model using GLM with Binomial family. It's not yet available for Logit (in module discrete_models).